# Deleted answers hard to identify

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Deleted answers to questions are very difficult to tell apart from regular answers - the color difference is very small and easy to miss.

Color code is #F4EAEA, i think something slightly darker like #EAA4A4 might work better.

[image]

Comment: The text could be made grey/lighter too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#EAA4A4 seems *too* jarring - it almost emphasizes deleted content when it should really be downplayed a bit.

Having said that, I agree that the existing color is a bit too light. Starting next build, we'll use the same deleted content background color here as we do on Stack Overflow. It should be easier to tell apart.